# systemd unit triggered on network interface

Tags: networking, systemd, systemd-unit

I'm new to systemd and unit files and I'm trying to find a way to have my unit running only when a network interface exist.

My unit file starts a web server and I only want it active when `wlan1` exist. I was looking at doing

```
[Path]
PathExists=/sys/class/net/wlan1
```

in my unit file, but I'm wondering if this is the best approach or is there a better way?

Comment: Is this interface typically available after startup? Trying to figure out if you just want your service to wait until networking is up, or if this network interface may not be up based on other conditions/factors.

Comment: @cherdt: it is not always up. The interface doesn't exist unless certain conditions exist.